# With ui-router how do I make nested instances of two different states with their own preserved routes?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have a page that I need nested states in. But not nested in the terms all the google search results come back with. I'm already using that and have no problems. The best way I can explain it is in a series of pictures.

Here is my page as it is currently set up

[image: Current setup]

Now when I click on one of the widgets above, for this example, say I click on the `notes` widget which is the fourth option. The following page will come up

[image: Current behaviour]

Right now what happens is I completely transition to a new state, my url changes from `myurl.com/call/{{assessorId}}/process/processType?=1` to `myurl.com/assessor/{{assessorId}}/detail/notes`

What I need to have happen is have the screen in the second picture appear but inside the bottom half of the first screen, like this picture I pieced together with some cropping in MS Paint

[image: Intended Behaviour]

The bottom half of the screen has it's own independent url that ui-router needs to track and follow as you move from one widget to another. The title bar that says `{{assessorName}} | Notes` is a home-brew breadcrumb solution which would enable navigating back to the original set of widgets.

So I have navigation down, but I don't have a way to keep the instance of that state inside of my current state. Instead I leave my `assessor.call` state and transition to my `assessor.detail.notes` state.

How do I instead keep my `assessor.call` state, and nest my

`assessor.detail.{{selectedWidget}}` state inside at the bottom of the page?

Comment: You say you're already using nested views with no problem, but this sounds like a classic nested views use case. The lower section of your page (blue outline) should be its own `ui-view` with a unique name so that you can target it in your routing config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multiple ui-view in a single html page,
for example

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="header" ui-view="header"></div>
  <div class="main" ui-view="main"></div>
  <div class="footer z-depth-3" ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Now you can have separate **view, controller, sass/css** for each ui-view.
Let say I have a module organisation which contains three parts, header, footer and main then in it's js I will write

```
$stateProvider.state('home.organisation',
            {
                url: '^/organisation',                   
                views: {
                    'header@home': {
                        templateUrl: 'navbar@organisation.html',
                        controllerAs: 'organisationNavbar',
                        controller: 'OrganisationNavbarCntrl'
                    },
                    'main@home': {
                        templateUrl: 'organisation.html',
                        controllerAs: 'organisation',
                        controller: 'OrganisationCntrl'
                    },
                    'footer@home': {
                        templateUrl:'footer@organisation.html',
                        controllerAs: 'organisationFooter',
                        controller: 'OrganisationFooterCntrl'
                    }
                }
            });
```